# Does a filter / StringSink allocated with new require a delete?

Tags: c++, new-operator, crypto++, delete-operator

Consider the code line:

```
StringSource( cipher ,
              true   ,
              new PK_DecryptorFilter( rng       ,
                                      decrypter ,
                                      new StringSink( plainText ) ) );
```

The filter and the `StringSink` object get created using `new` now I'm curious whether I'm responsible for deleting those as I'm unsure how I would do that since I would need the pointers to these objects.

When looking at the test projects I can't seem to find a delete so I'm guessing these objects automatically get deleted once their job is fulfillled.

But since documentations can be wrong I figured I'd make sure.

Comment: `StringSource(cipher, ...)` is an anonymous declaration. You should name them like `StringSource ss(cipher, ...)`. Anonymous declarations give some versions of GCC problems. The problem is GCC generates code where the destructors run too soon, so the transformation never takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [header](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/filters_8h_source.html) and [source](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/filters_8cpp_source.html) for those classes, both of them end up assigning their attachment to a `member_ptr` which deals with the deletion automatically. You shouldn't delete them yourself, just let the library handle it.

Comment: sweet less trouble for me :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does a filter / StringSink allocated with new require a delete?

In the case you provided, the answer is NO. You don't need to delete it. From `Readme.txt` under *Important Usage Notes*:

> 1. If a constructor for A takes a pointer to an object B (except primitive types such as int and char), then A owns B and will delete B
>      at A's destruction.  If a constructor for A takes a reference to an
>      object B, then the caller retains ownership of B and should not
>      destroy it until A no longer needs it.

Also see the Crypto++ wiki page on [Pipelining](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining). Its a higher level design perspective, and object ownership is a detail of it.

---

There's a second important note listed in the `Readme.txt`. Here it is:

> 2. Crypto++ is thread safe at the class level. This means you can use Crypto++ safely in a multithreaded application, but you must provide
>      synchronization when multiple threads access a common Crypto++ object.